# Shared Preferences not working with Contacts in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences, android-contacts

I've basically got this list view which pulls up phone and numbers of the existing user contacts in the device and populates it. I want to be able to select the phone/numbers and save them as long as the device is still there. My three questions:

- The shared preferences doesn't save properly any ideas?
- Also I'd like to add either a checkbox or colour to identify whats selected and not selected an ideas?
- How to display the thumbnail photo of the user contact from the phone using contactscontract any ideas? (I've tried this) ->

  String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_PHOTO,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_FILE_ID};

This produces and error in my Adapter, not sure how to fix.

Class:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class UserContacts extends ListActivity {


    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor1;
    String spref_identifier = "com.example.app";
    String entryIdentifierPrefix = "selectionState_listEntry_";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_contacts);

        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);

        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};


        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2,cursor1,from,to);

        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            saveSelectedState(position, true);
            refreshList();
        }
    });

}


private void saveSelectedState(int entryPosition, boolean selectedState) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    spe.putString(entryIdentifierPrefix + entryPosition, selectedState); spe.commit(); }


private boolean getSelectedState(int entryPosition) {
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getString(entryIdentifierPrefix + entryPosition, false);
    // Default value is set as false. Tweak this if necessary.
    }

    private void refreshList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) { lv.setItemChecked(getSelectedItemPosition(), getSelectedState(i)); }
    }

    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homescreen:
                homescreenItem();
                return true;
            case R.id.dashboard:
                dashboardItem();
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                aboutItem();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void homescreenItem(){
        startActivity(new Intent(UserContacts.this, Home.class));
    }

    private void dashboardItem(){
        startActivity(new Intent(UserContacts.this, Dashboard.class));
    }

    private void aboutItem(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("About")
                .setMessage("Welcome to Save Me! An interactive and intuitive way to protect yourself during emergency situations and keep your location privacy. Made for a Dissertation and Developed by Ankhit Sharma")
                .setNeutralButton("OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
    }


}
```

XML Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserContacts">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For the first question , If you are using a cursor adapter, you can get the phone no/name from the cursor value and save it in the shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used boolean type and trying to save string value due to which your was not storing in the preference

```
private void saveSelectedState(int entryPosition, boolean selectedState) {
 SharedPreferences.Editor spe = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
spe.putBoolean(entryIdentifierPrefix + entryPosition, selectedState); spe.commit();
 }


 private boolean getSelectedState(int entryPosition) { 
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
return sp.getBoolean(entryIdentifierPrefix + entryPosition, false);
 // Default value is set as false. Tweak this if necessary.
 }
```

Try this. Here I have saved the value in the preference with string type

```
private void saveSelectedState(String keyname, int position) { 
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 spe.putString(keyname,entryIdentifierPrefix + entryPosition); spe.commit(); }


 private boolean getSelectedState(String keyname) {
 SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences( spref_identifier, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
return sp.getString(keyname, "");
 // Default value is set as blank. Tweak this if necessary. 
}
```

And for displaying a display pic

```
image_uri = cur .getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

if (image_uri != null) { 
System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri)); 
try { 
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(image_uri));

 System.out.println(bitmap); 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Cheers for the swift response, however, when I change the the boolean to a String, I get an error (Java Lang exception) can't change string if they are Boolean. In regards to the image but where exactly do I place it, since I putting it in between the String[] and Int[] I get errors with variables I've not declared? Apologies I'm a novice.

Comment: Use this line for saving state in onitemclick saveselectedstate(position, true);

Comment: I've amended the code, check above for reference, still errors on the get and save states methods. It says put string in Editor can't be applied to.../get string can't be applied to Shared Pref to string boolean

Comment: I've checked...still no dice...It doesn't reference correctly with the other bits of code in the section above. Conflicts between int/string.

Comment: try to spend sometime on the code, you will understand

Comment: So I tried having a look properly and I've done the changes however, the onitemclick still gives me the errors cause the adapter view wont change to a String value. Could you please show me more explicitly how you've managed to get it working? Also the image bit doesn't work...called and declared a new Cursor variable cur yet when I add it to the SimpleListAdapter it gives an error which if I remove breaks everything.